# React EdiText - Submit with Enter keypress

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

In [React EdiText](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editext), how to submit on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press?

Answer (score 0):

**onSave** props will help you catch the value user already typed.

[image]

Comment: OnSave doesn't seem to get key press events. Please see Repl [here](https://repl.it/repls/DearestSaltyUnix).

Answer (score 0):

Component's author has released a new version 3.9.0 with [submitOnEnter](https://alioguzhan.github.io/react-editext/#submit-on-enter) switch.